# find invariant subspace of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, representation-theory, invariant-theory

For each real $t$, we define an operator $L(t)$, acting on functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, by setting $(L(t)f)(x)=f(x-t)$ for all functions $f$ and all reals $x$.

I know that $L$ is representation of the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ on the space of functions (or continuous functions) defined on the real line. It restricts to a representation of $\mathbb{R}$ on the space $\mathcal{P}$ of univariate polynomials $\mathbb{R}\left[x\right]$ (which we consider as embedded into the space of functions).

> Find all the invariant subspaces of polynomials of $L$ (that is, all subrepresentations of the representation $L$ on $\mathcal{P}$).

Comment: What about constant polynomials?

Comment: @user115654 Perhaps subspaces of polynomials of oder $k$ are the invariant subspaces of polynomials of $L$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $V = \mathbb{R}[x]$ and let $V_n$ be its subspace of polynomials of order at most $n$. Each $V_n$ is $L(\mathbb{R})$-stable. Note that $V_n = 0$ if $n$ is negative.

Let $\Delta : V \to V$ be the linear operator $L(0) - L(1)$. Then $(\Delta f)(x) = f(x) - f(x-1)$ so $\Delta(V_n) \subseteq V_{n-1}$ and $\Delta(x^n) \equiv n x^{n-1} \mod V_{n-2}$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Let $W$ be some $L(\mathbb{R})$-stable subspace. Then $\Delta(W) \subseteq W$. Let $n$ be largest possible integer such that $W$ contains $V_n$ (if it exists). We will show that $W = V_n$ in this case.

Suppose for a contradiction that $f(x) \in W \backslash V_n$. Then $f(x) \equiv ax^m \mod V_{m-1}$ for some non-zero $a$ and some $m \geq n+1$, so

$(\Delta^{m-n-1} f)(x) = a m (m-1) \cdots (n+2) x^{n+1} + v \in W$

for some $v \in V_n$. Since $am(m-1) \cdots (n+2) \neq 0$ and $v \in V_n \subseteq W$ we get $x^{n+1}\in W$ and hence $V_{n+1} \subseteq W$. This contradicts the maximality of $n$.

Therefore either $W = V_n$ for some $n$, or no such $n$ exists in which case $W$ contains all $V_m$ and hence $W = V$.

Thus $0 = V_{-1} \subset V_0 \subset V_1 \subset \cdots \subset \bigcup V_n = V$ are the only possible $L(\mathbb{R})$-stable subspaces of $V$.

Comment: I am wondering why $ mod V_{n-2}$ in the forth line, could you please explain this for me?

Comment: I think it is for removing any other polynomials of degree < n-1 ..... am I correct?

Comment: I could not understand the fifth line from below. what makes $x^{n +1} \in W$

Comment: @hopefully : (i) Because $\Delta(x^n)$ has a leading term $nx^{n-1}$ and other monomials of degree less than $n-2$; (ii) $v\in W$ and $v+\lambda x^{n+1}\in W$ for some nonzero $\lambda$, hence $x^{n+1} = \frac{1}{\lambda}( (v+\lambda x^{n+1}) - v)$ is also in $W$

Comment: @Max did  you mean other polynomials of degree less than $n -1$ in your previous comment?

Comment: @hopefully : less than $n-2$, strictly less than $n-1$

Comment: okay that is fine @Max your less than means $\leq$

Comment: @Max could you please answer my second comment? (the second line after the answer)

Comment: I already did, this was part of my (i) comment

Comment: It seems like the operator delta defined above is the differentiation operator and we know one differentiation decreases the power by one and we do $m-(n + 1)$ differentiations because we require $x^{n + 1}$ to appear and since we assumed at the beginning towards contradiction that $f(x) \in W/V_{n}$ then its differentiation is in $W/V_{n}$ ..... so I could not understand why you said $ v + \lambda x^{n +1} \in W$ and you do not say that it is in $W/V_{n}$ ..... could you clarify this point for me please? @Max

Comment: Sorry @Max I realized that if it is in $W/V_{n}$ sure it will be in $W$