# A difficulty in understanding the solution of #2 section 1 Vinberg.

Tags: representation-theory, invariant-theory

The question and its answer is given below:

[image]

[image]

But I do not know how I should think to find all the invariant subspaces and why the answer is as mentioned above, could anyone explain this for me please?

**Edit:**

I found an answer to this question here [find invariant subspace of polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638719/find-invariant-subspace-of-polynomials)  but still I do not understand the answer, could anyone clarify this answer for me please? at least the intuition behind it and the general idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Are we sure that this list is complete? What about just normalized quadratic polynomials, for example?

Comment: @Klaus Yes, the list is complete. But I agree with your objection. And there are lots of other possibilities. What about, for instance, the space of those polynomials with one and only one real root?

Comment: Are "subspaces" to be understood as "vector subspaces"? Because then, normalized quadratic polynomials are not an answer, and the answer is indeed correct.

Comment: yes they are to be understood as vector spaces @darijgrinberg ...... could you please explain for me why the solution as described above because you seem to have a deep understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch of a solution (so as to not give everything away) :

If $V$ is an invariant subspace, let $x^n+q(x)$ be some element of $V$, with $\deg q < n$. By using some translation, show that there is $x^n+p(x)\in V$ with $\deg p<n-1$.

Again using some translation, deduce that there is $x^n+x^{n-1}+r(x)\in V$ for some $r$ with $\deg r < n-1$. Conclude that some $x^{n-1} + h(x) \in V$ with $\deg h < n-1$. By induction, deduce that there is a constant in $V$, then by going back up, deduce that for $k\leq n$, $x^k\in V$

Conclude.

Comment: so we go down to get the constant polynomial (the null space) from V then return back up to prove the existence of the space of polynomials of degree $\leq$ n for arbitrary n in V ..... correct ? what about the whole space of polynomials (the infinite space ) how will we proof that it is in V ?

Comment: Max I have a question about the solution the OP mentioned in the above link that I wrote below the solution there could you please see it for me because the author of the solution there or the editor are not answering? ..... thank you

Comment: @hopefully In general the whole space of polynomials need not be in $V$, $\mathbf{R}_{\leq n}[x]$ is invariant ! You have to distinguish the case where polynomials in $V$ have bounded degree, and the case where they don't.

Comment: but I think this is covered(the unbounded polynomials) in the answer mentioned above Max. ..... am I correct? or it needs more details?

Comment: I think in your fifth line it should be $x^n + x^{n-1} + h(x)$ am I correct Max?

Comment: @hopefully : No, that was in the 4th line; the fifth line should read $x^{n-1}+h(x)$, that's the whole point

Comment: Okay ..... thank you :)

Comment: Just want to ask Max is the procedure you described here is the one used in the link mentioned above by the OP?

Comment: @hopefully : no not exactly

Comment: A part of that used in the link mentioned by the OP?